# Converter um ArrayList de String em um Json

Tags: java, android

Estou precisando converter um `ArrayList` de `String` em um JSON.

Tenho um método no qual recebo uma lista de apps instalados no aparelho celular. Este método me retorna os dados em um ArrayList de String.

Eu consegui gerar um JSON usando `JSONArray` mas não consegui inserir uma tag dentro do Json, segue abaixo o JSON utilizando `JSONArray`.

```
Json: ["com.br.package1", "com.br.package2", "com.br.package3"]
```

Preciso que o Json fique da seguinte forma:

```
[{"name": "com.br.package1"},{"name": "com.br.package2"}, {"name":"com.br.package3"}]
```

Segue abaixo um trecho do código:

```
//Cria e inicializa ArrayList que contem os packages instalados no Aparelho
ArrayList<String> mPackages = new ArrayList<String>();

//Grava no ArrayList o retorno do método
mPackages = Util.buscaAppsInstalados(getBaseContext());

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(mPackages);
```

Comment: Esse "name" é fixo?

Comment: Olá Pablo sim é fixo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terá de construir primeiro um *JSONObject* por cada item de `mPackages` e adicioná-lo ao *JSONArray*:

```
//Cria e inicializa ArrayList que contem os packages instalados no Aparelho
ArrayList<String> mPackages = new ArrayList<String>();

//Grava no ArrayList o retorno do método
mPackages = Util.buscaAppsInstalados(getBaseContext());

//Cria um JSONArray
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

//Percorre mPackages
for(String name : mPackages){

    //Cria um JSONObject por cada item
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        //Constroi o JSONObject
        jsonObject.put("name", name);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Adiciona-o ao JSONArray
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.